# Can not install gem package with my own user during chef compilation

Tags: rubygems, chef-infra, bundler

I am new to chef, just trying to install gem package with the following code in chef recipe before I could use this subsequently:

```rb
gem_package 'bundler:1.6.5' do
  options "--user-install www"
  action :nothing
end.run_action(:install)
```

The problem is bundler gets installed , but under the root user not with www. I have tried everything. Is this is bug or I am doing something wrong here. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

```
%w[clc-gem1 clc-gem2 clc_gem-amazing].each do |gem|
  gem_package gem do
    source node["clc_nexus"]["repo"]["localgems"]
    gem_binary "/opt/chefdk/embedded/bin/gem"
    options "--no-user-install"
    action :upgrade
  end
end
```

you need to specify `--no-user-install` option. Since chef is running as root, if this is not specified, the gems are installed in /home/root. By specifying `--no-user-install`, the gems are installed in the shared ruby gems location. This may not be ideal and I'm sure there must be a way to get it in the vagrant user directory, but for the purposes of our vagrant environments, this works well.